# Windows Server 2008 R2 Apache 2.2 PHP 5.3.3 install issue

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

I am trying to install Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.3 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box. I've managed to setup Apache, but PHP is not working correctly: I've downloaded the latest zip from windows.php.net (VC6) and I've modified http.conf in order to load the php5 module (`LoadModule`, `AddType` & `PHPIniDir`). So far, so good - `phpinfo()` is showing and I am happy... But, there is no php.ini file - I haven't yet renamed the bundled php.ini-development|php.ini-production file. If I do so (in order to modify PHP's configuration), no php code is interpreted (including `phpinfo()`). I've gone over the entire php.ini-development file and still it is not working... This is very strange.

If I use the renamed php.ini-production, I get a blank page. If I don't define a php.ini or php.ini is empty, `phpinfo()` is working and the loaded configuration file is C:\Php\php.ini (I've installed php in C:\Php) ... This is driving me insane...

Any help is welcome, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this very same issue in a CLI only setup.

I got it resolved by disabling all extensions that I'm not needing.  I can't tell you wich extension is the booger here, as I stopped troubleshooting as soon as it worked.  I only needed ODBC and some basics (like eg. zip)